# What is the default value of lastIndexOf?

Tags: javascript, string, indexof

`string.lastIndexOf(searchValue[, fromIndex])`

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) says that `fromIndex` default value is equal to the `string.length`, however, I really think it is `string.length-1`

But it doesn't matter what I think... I need someone to confirm what is the default value of `fromIndex`

**Here is what they say:**

> *"It can be any integer between 0 and the length of the string. The default value is the length of the string."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to ECMAScript 5, it will be the `length` of the String.

> **15.5.4.8 String.prototype.lastIndexOf (searchString, position)**
>
> If `position` is `undefined`, the `length` of the String value is assumed, so as to search all of the String.
>
> ...
>
> 1. Call `CheckObjectCoercible` passing the this value as its argument.
> 2. Let `S` be the result of calling `ToString`, giving it the this value as its argument.
> 3. Let `searchStr` be `ToString(searchString)`.
> 4. **Let `numPos` be `ToNumber(position)`. (If position is undefined, this step produces the value `NaN`).**
> 5. If `numPos` is `NaN`, let pos be `+∞;` otherwise, let `pos` be `ToInteger(numPos)`.
> 6. Let `len` be the number of characters in `S`.
> 7. Let `start` `min(max(pos, 0), len)`.
> 8. Let `searchLen` be the number of characters in `searchStr`.
> 9. Return the largest possible nonnegative integer k not larger than start such that k+ searchLen is not greater than len, and for all nonnegative integers j less than searchLen, the character at position k+j of S is the same as the character at position j of searchStr; but if there is no such integer k, then return the value -1.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter, at all.  Since the index is zero-based, both `string.length` and `string.length-1` will include the entire string.

**EDIT**

You can test for differences in the result pretty simply:

```
var s = '01923456789abcdef';
alert(s.lastIndexOf('f',s.length+1));
alert(s.lastIndexOf('f',s.length));
alert(s.lastIndexOf('f',s.length-1));
alert(s.lastIndexOf('f',s.length-2));
```

That alerts 16, 16, 16, -1.   Thus, if you are very concerned with an extra few cycles being used when a useragent runs `.lastIndexOf()`, you can pass `.length-1` and have it spend a few extra cycles parsing the extra parameter.

Comment: It matters to me, the performance is the key of success. One extra loop will lead to failure in life

Comment: I am very curious what situation you are coding in that a few potential cycles on the user agent make all the difference in success.

Answer (score 0):

If fromIndex is as large or larger than the string length, the function returns -1.

If not, the string.substring(fromIndex) searches from the end of the substring.